# Using $setOnInsert on Upsert With mgo Driver

Tags: mongodb, go, upsert, mgo

How do you use `$setOnInsert` on an `Upsert` with any of the `mgo` variants of the Go MongoDB drivers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the arbitrary type `Foo`:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    ID       bson.ObjectId `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Bar      string        `json:"bar" bson:"bar"`
    Created  *time.Time    `json:"created,omitempty" bson:"created,omitempty"`
    Modified *time.Time    `json:"modified,omitempty" bson:"modified,omitempty"`
}
```

And the `Upsert` selector, which determines whether or not this will be an `Update` or an `Insert`:

```golang
selector := bson.M{
    "bar": "bar",
}
```

The `Upsert` query to insert a created date only if the document is being inserted will look like this (where `now` is a variable of type `time.Time`):

```golang
query := bson.M{
    "$setOnInsert": bson.M{
        "created": &now,
    },
    "$set": Foo{
        Bar:      "bar",
        Modified: &now,
    },
}
```

Using all of these defined types and variables with the `globalsign/mgo` driver, this entire query is executed by the following code:

```golang
if _, err := session.DB("test").C("test").Upsert(selector, query); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: For anyone that follow the answer and got this error: "Cannot update <field> and <field> at the same time". You're missing `omitempty` in the model, or you can change `"$set": Foo[}` to `"$set": bson.M{}`